# SwiftUI: Add Items dynamically to TabView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, tabview

i want to use TabView to display some data. I'm using paged view style for this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var texts: [String] = ["first", "second"]

  var body: some View {
    TabView {

        ForEach(texts, id: \.self) { text in
            VStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    texts.append("next one...")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                })
                
                Text(text)
            }
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
  }
}
```

As expected the view comes up to display two pages ("first" and "second"). When i'm pressing the button a new page indicator is added (so i see three dots in the page index) but i can't scroll to the third page.

Am i missing something, or is this a bug in Xcode?

Comment: side note: if i drop the PageTabViewStyle it seems to work as expected

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63500070/12299030?

Comment: absolutely! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

So as Asperi already pointed out the same beheaviour was seen in [TabView with "PageTabViewStyle" does not update it's content when @State var changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499707/tabview-with-pagetabviewstyle-does-not-update-its-content-when-state-var-cha/63500070#63500070)

I also found this post which references the same answer: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/how-do-i-append-a-new-page-into-tabview-pagetabviewstyle/2583

**The solution would be to ad an .id( id value ) to the TabView, so that it reloads completely.**