# How to hide/remove views from tabview after button click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am currently using a tabview to allow my app to scroll horizontally. At the end of the tabview the user ends up on a register page where they can either click login or sign up. When they click either I want to direct them to a new view where they can't scroll back to register page. Currently after they click login or sign up a new view pops up, but you can still scroll back to the previous pages in the tabview. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        TabView {
            ForEach(0..<5) {i in
                if(i == 0) {
                    FirstPageView()
                } else if(i == 1) {
                    SecondPageView()
                } else if(i == 2) {
                    ThirdPageView()
                } else {
                    RegisterView()
                }
            }
        }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        
    }
    
}
```

}

Register View:

```
struct RegisterView: View {

var body: some View {
    let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
    
    let screen_width = screen.size.width
    
    let screen_height = screen.size.height
    
    let theme_color =
        Color(hue: 0.636, saturation: 0.646, brightness: 0.994)
    
    NavigationView{
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            Text("Investing App.")
                .foregroundColor(theme_color)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size:screen_width/8))
                .padding(.leading)
            
            
            Text("Start investing")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size:screen_width/8))
                .padding(.leading)
            
            
            Text("today.")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size:screen_width/8))
                .padding(.leading)
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SignUpView(),
                label: {
                    Text("Login")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .font(.system(size:screen_width/25))
                        .frame(width: screen_width/5, height: screen_width/9, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        
                        .padding(.horizontal, screen_width/3)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                })
            
            
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            
            
            .offset(y:screen_height/2.5)
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SignUpView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Sign Up")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.system(size:screen_width/25))
                            .frame(width: screen_width/5, height: screen_width/9, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                            .padding(.horizontal, screen_width/3)
                            .overlay(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                            )
                    })
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    
                    
                    .offset(y:screen_height/5)
            
                
                
            
        }
        .padding()
        .offset(y: -screen_height/4+42.4)
        .frame(width: screen_width, height: screen_height/2, alignment: .leading)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
   
}
```

}

Thank you!

Comment: I would ask whether a tab view was the correct architecture for this.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure what architecture I should use

Comment: Well maybe that's what your question should have been about, then. I mean, I think what you've learned so far is that a tab view isn't it, because it allows the user to see any of the tabs at any time. That isn't what you want so that isn't what you should use.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: You can use a NavigationView instead of TabView in your ContentView. Then you can push the correct view using a NavigationLink

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63500070/12299030?

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite, after swiping through the first views the user will end up on the register view where they will either click signup/login and be redirected to a new view. Currently after they are redirected they can still swipe back to the previous pages.