# How do I get UIViewControllerRepresentable to work with searchable

Tags: swiftui, uikit, uipageviewcontroller, swiftui-tabview

I've been having issues getting a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` wrapping a `UIPageViewController` to play nicely with SwiftUI. Specifically, I can't get the `searchable` modifier to work properly when the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` is in the view hierarchy. This modifier works properly if I replace the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` with a `TabView` with a `.tabViewStyle(.page)`.

Here's some sample code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var search = ""

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ControllerPager()
        .navigationTitle("Title")
    }
    .searchable(text: $search)
  }
}

struct ControllerPager: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
    UIPageViewController(
      transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
  }

  func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
    pageViewController.setViewControllers(
      [UIHostingController(rootView: Page())],
      direction: .forward,
      animated: true)
  }
}

struct NativePager: View {
  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      Page()
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
  }
}

struct Page: View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(0..<100) { i in
        Text("\(i)")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

With this code (where I'm not using a `TabView`), the `searchable` box doesn't appear in the `NavigationView`. If I replace the `ControllerPager()` with `NativePager()` it does.

For those wondering why I'm using `UIViewControllerRepresentable` instead of a `TabView`, I need a dynamic data source for the `UIPageViewController` that updates as the user swipes between pages. I tried [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499707/tabview-with-pagetabviewstyle-does-not-update-its-content-when-state-var-cha/63500070#63500070) but the `TabView` behaved strangely as I was changing the state while the user was swiping between pages.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```swift
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        Text(" ")

        ControllerPager()
          .navigationTitle("Title")
        }
    }
    .searchable(text: $search)
  }
```

I used Xcode's Capture View Hierarchy debugging and saw that both the `ControllerPager` and `NativePager` were adding a `UISearchBar`, but the `ControllerPager`'s height was larger, seemingly covering over the `UISearchBar`.

While looking through tutorials on SwiftUI layout I saw somewhere that `UIViewControllerRepresentable` needs a `frame` to properly work with the SwiftUI layout system. Some people solved this by adding fixed height frames to their `UIViewControllerRepresentable` but that seemed kinda hacky for something that should just take up as much space as it needs. I played around wrapping different parts in `GeometryReader`s to be able to compute a proper frame but it would always return a height that was too large.

I was then curious as to how Apple solved this in their [Interfacing with UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) tutorial. The key that I originally missed was that their end solution uses a `ZStack` with the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` wrapping a `UIPageViewController` **and** a `UIViewRepresentable` wrapping a `UIPageControl`. So something in that `ZStack` could properly interface with the SwiftUI layout system and the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` would simply inherit the frame that was computed for it.

A `Text` with a single space as content is a bit hacky but what I found was that I needed an element that would get "rendered". If I set `.opacity(0)`, used an empty `VStack`, or used something like `Color(uiColor: .clear)` it wouldn't work. Even with something like `Text("hello")`, that text would never actually be visible, even as I swiped between pages.

Now that I have a handle on what the actual issue is I'll look for less hacky solutions, but for now, this works.